# How to make a polygon from from a shape that's a result of subtraction

Tags: javafx

How to make a polygon from from a shape that's a result of subtraction. It starts off with one polygon (`poly1`). Then another polygon is added (`poly2`) which intersects the first one. I subtract `poly2` from `poly1`, which leaves me with an instance of `Shape` (remained). I would like to make a new polygon from what's left of `poly1` after the subtraction (remained). Couldn't find a way to do it. Can you help please?

[image]

```
Polygon poly1, poly2; 
Shape remained;
…
remained = Shape.subtract(poly1, poly2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this operation will in general be a Path and you can iterate over its elements like this and create a new Polygon from them.

```
    Path path = (Path)remained;
    for (PathElement pe : path.getElements()) {
        ...
    }
```

But you have to make sure that the result of this operation actually is a polygon because this may not be the case.

Comment: Thank you, @mipa, it works very well. Got all the points to make the new polygon.